# webkitSpeechGrammarList() really works?

Tags: javascript, webspeech-api, google-speech-api

I am trying to implement a [webkitSpeechGrammarList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechGrammarList). Like you see bellow. But when I say a word that it is outside of my `grammar` I will have the result instead of `"I didnt recognise that color"`.

```
var grammar = '#JSGF V1.0; grammar colors; public <color> = aqua | azure | beige | bisque | black | blue | brown | chocolate | coral | crimson | cyan | fuchsia | ghostwhite | gold | goldenrod | gray | green | indigo | ivory | khaki | lavender | lime | linen | magenta | maroon | moccasin | navy | olive | orange | orchid | peru | pink | plum | purple | red | salmon | sienna | silver | snow | tan | teal | thistle | tomato | turquoise | violet | white | yellow ;'
var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
var speechRecognitionList = new webkitSpeechGrammarList();
speechRecognitionList.addFromString(grammar, 1);
recognition.grammars = speechRecognitionList;
//recognition.continuous = false;
recognition.lang = 'en-US';
recognition.interimResults = false;
recognition.maxAlternatives = 1;



var diagnostic = document.querySelector('.output');
var bg = document.querySelector('html');


recognition.start();


recognition.onresult = function(event) {
  var color = event.results[0][0].transcript;
  diagnostic.textContent = 'Result received: ' + color + '.';
  bg.style.backgroundColor = color;
}

recognition.onspeechend = function() {
  recognition.stop();
}

recognition.onnomatch = function(event) {
  diagnostic.textContent = 'I didnt recognise that color.';
}
```

So, because this is all experimental technology. I am wondering.. This is really implemented? How can I know that?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this moment the grammars are [ignored](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/content/browser/speech/google_streaming_remote_engine.cc&l=320).

Comment: Dead link. This is why quality answers aren't link only.

Comment: @FredGandt What are you even talking about??! The link works perfectly fine

Comment: No supporting information is available at the source (which may have been dead at my time of posting), a more specific link should be provided and without that link this answer hardly qualifies as one. Maybe consider calming down??!